# localStorage with angularJS - how to dynamic bind value to all tabs in browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am having 2 file, index.html and server.js.

I am using localstorage to save text between tabs. my code is below.
2 questions:
1. will this be saved if I will close the browser (if I will turn down the computer?).
2. how can I change this code to dymanic change the value in all the open tabs? currently it just disaplay the new value when I open a new tab/press refresh on an old tab...

Thanks

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script  src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1></h1>
    <h2>Current LocalStorage value is = {{ msg }} </h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <input type="button" value="save value" ng-click="update(value)">
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var app;
app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function(myLocalStorage, $scope) {

  $scope.msg = myLocalStorage.getData();

  $scope.update = function(msgContent) {
   $scope.msg = myLocalStorage.setData(msgContent);
 };

});
app.factory("myLocalStorage", function($window) {
  return {
    setData: function(val) {
      $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.setItem('my-storage', val);
      return val;
    },
    getData: function() {
      return $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.getItem('my-storage');
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody already answered: yes, local storage will keep its values even after the browser is turned off.

Another tip is to use ngStorage for angular, so that you can use

```
$localStorage.setItem();
```

I recommend you check out their documentation for easier local/sessionstorage handling

**Answer edited based on reply:**

Try adding a watch listener like so:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
   return $window.localStorage.getItem('my-storage');
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
       return;
    }
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.update(newVal);  
        //$scope.onIdChange(newVal, oldVal); // If you need oldVal
    }        
});
```

If you really want a user to have multiple browsertabs open of the same website, I don't think it's possible to dynamically change the content on both tabs (Which are the same view) based on the localstorage.

Comment: thank you.. what I am trying to acomplish is a way to dymanic bind my storage between all the open tabs.. meaning once I change txt in one tab.. what happen to all the other txt in the other tabs? you got it... they get updated automatically.. something like: $window.on('storage', this.onStorageChanged) the guy above e suggested.. but where should I put this line in my code? and what is the corret syntax?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. It will.
2. You should subscribe on storage change event

   ```
   $window.on('storage', this.onStorageChanged);
   ```

Comment: thanks.. where do I put this line and what does it do?